# Configuring events on the amazon managed blockchain

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-managed-blockchain

How do i Configure events on the amazon managed blockchain

I have configured amazon managed blockchain setup with Hyperledger. The network is prepared with a single member and a single peer node. Hyperledger Fabric Client setup is with Golang 1.10.3.

Chaincode has been coded in golang

I need event service to be configured so that external services coded in nodejs can subscribe to it and act upon the events